# How to store response of each questions in scorm

Tags: php, moodle, scorm, scorm1.2

I'am new to **SCORM** development.

After a few research we found that PHP is not good for developing SCORM package and we converted all of our php pages into pure HTML&javascript.

Now we have a basic SCORM package with basic functionalities like session calculation.

How to send response of each questions to LMS in scorm?

currently i'am using *'reload-editor*' and *'ReloadScormPlayer1.2.2'* is there any better software?

can i use **Moodle** for this?

Comment: You are building a PHP based LMS?  Or your trying to build PHP based SCORM content object i.e. a SCO?  Note: the "S" in SCO is shareable, so PHP would not be recommended.  Either way the SCORM communication model is mostly JavaScript with the exception to your backend server which can be PHP to accept student attempt CMI Objects.  Moodle supports PHP and SCORM 1.2 (not 2004).

Comment: Thanks @Mark , i am trying to build PHP based SCORM content object. is there any problem for using PHP and my codes are mostly client side. and i have to build a basic SCORM but now i need to calulate the session time, where i can find a tutorial for that?

Answer (score 1):

Moodle is used to deliver `SCORM` content rather than create it. So you would create a `SCORM` package in an editor, then create a `SCORM` activity in Moodle and upload the `SCORM` package.

```
https://docs.moodle.org/34/en/Creating_SCORM_Content
```

I would suggest looking at Adapt which is an open source SCORM editor :

```
https://www.adaptlearning.org/
```

Or have a look at Adobe Captivate which is a commercial editor :

```
https://www.adobe.com/products/captivate.html
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice , do i need to download the Adapt authoring tool or Framework ? which is better for converting an HTML solution to SCORM

Answer (score 1):

You can use cmi.interactions to store answers to questions in the LMS database.

Rustici have a [runtime reference for all scorm versions here](https://scorm.com/scorm-explained/technical-scorm/run-time/run-time-reference/) , this shows the calls you can make to the API.

A very simple answer could be stored in the LMS by getting the number of interactions:

```
NUM = cmi.interactions._count
```

Then pushing in some basic data:

```
cmi.interactions.NUM.id = "question_id_with_no_spaces"
cmi.interactions.NUM.learner_response = "A,B,D"
cmi.interactions.NUM.result = "correct".
```

This should work on Moodle, but [SCORM Cloud](https://cloud.scorm.com/sc/guest/SignInForm) is a great place to test and debug the information your package is sending.

SCORM 2004 (both versions) have more option and are worth exploring as not all LMS can take interactions from a 1.2 SCORM.